# how to display the "Game over" image in android for a fixed amount of time and restart the game when user taps the screen after a specified interval?

Tags: java, android

I made clone of ""Flappy bird" game by watching video tutorials.i programmed it so that when the bird falls or collides with the tubes a game over message appears on the screen and the game restarts when the player taps on the screen.

The problem is that when the user fails to tap the bird in time and it collides with the tube,the game over screen appears immediately and the user happens to tap on the game over screen which results in restarting of the game.

This makes the user unable to see the score.I have already tried using Thread.sleep().Following is the code

```
    (gameState == 2)
    {
        batch.draw(gameOver,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-gameOver.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-gameOver.getHeight()/2);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            gameState = 1;
            startGame();
            score =0;
            scoringTube = 0;
            velocity = 0;
        }
    }
```

With this code the problem is that even the gameover image is being delayed and the previous problem is still occuring but now with a delay.I basically need a way so that justTouched method becomes inactive for a while when the game over screen is there.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend using `Thread.sleep`; instead, you could try to use a boolean that is changed once the game ended, and prevent the method from executing in that case. Combine that with e.g a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that resets it after a fixed delay, and you should have the solution to your problem.

Example Usage for the timer:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //execute code here (change boolean state)
        }
    }, 
    yourDelayHere 
);
```